# Fix IOS 8.1 Mail Threading to match osx

Tags: mail.app, email, ios

I noticed, after updating I believe, that the inbox of the mail app in IOS 8.1 only lists emails coming in, so making out the back and forth conversation that often replies turn into is impossible.

On my mac, it still groups in and outgoing emails in the same thread (ordered by time) so that the conversation becomes apparent.

I've been looking into turning on the "send hidden copies to me" option, but it doesn't seem like a very sustainable option if I'd export my mail to some other client some time in the future. And also, it gets naggy having it notify you for an incoming mail every time you send one out.
Does anyone have any other ideas of how to fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Tap on the More button after swiping left and you’ll find a new option to show related messages.

Source : http://www.maclife.com/article/features/50-ios-8-tips-and-tricks

Comment: ... though i've just tried it & I don't see the option...

Comment: I'm able to find it. However, this seems more like a workaround than a fix. I'll wait around and see if anyone else has a good idea of a fix, if there even is on, before I accept your answer.